# Shorten this if statement in Razor to one line

Tags: razor

Can i shorten this to one line? I have tried various ways but can't quite get it right.

```
@if(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact")
{
    @:<div class="contact">
}
```

Comment: There is probably a better way to do it without imbalanced tags.  Please show more code.

Comment: This the if statement I want shortened. Other code is irrelevant.

Comment: Wrong.  This `if` statement is poor design.  Given other code, we can show how to design it better.

Comment: Right. That's why i'm posting here to optimize this if statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There might be an even simpler solution but this should work:

```
@Html.Raw((SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact") ? "<div class='contact'>" : "")
```

Comment: Be careful with Html.Raw, doesn't encode the output!

Answer (score 20):

The shortest possible way to do is like:

```
@(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact" ? "<div class='contact'>" : "")
```

or

```
@(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact" ? @"<div class=""contact"">" : "")
```

or even shorter if you don't repeat your html code

```
<div class="@(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact" ? "contact" : "")">
```

Comment: This is the best approach for me, just a very readable and common C# syntax

Answer (score 15):

Another way would be:

```
@if(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact") { <text><div class="contact"></text> }
```

I personally find it more readable than the ternary operator, but this is personal

Comment: I like the readability of this one too but the only problem is that when you hit CTRL K+D in Visual Studio it drops it down to 3 lines :(

Answer (score 0):

This will work

Razor Syntax

```
@(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title == "Contact" ? "<div class='contact'>")
```