# C# how to print hard code value in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It might be silly to ask but still i am not able to google it correctly.
Below is my code to print "selected" in view:

```
<option value="0" @if(ViewBag.country == 0)  { @:selected } >NO</option>
```

it is giving me error like

```
Parser Error Message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

Referred :https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: Why can't you use the selected parameter of mvc dropdownList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ?: notation for inline code

`<option value="0" @(ViewBag.country == 0 ? "selected" : string.Empty)>NO</option>`

Comment: getting error " Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'"

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this

Create the value like this

```
@{ var selected = ViewBag.country == 0 ? "selected" : ""; }
```

and then create the option like below

```
<option value="0" @selected>NO</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) post.

> To explicitly indicate the beginning of a line of content by using the
>   @: character sequence within a code block.

To Make your code work take closing curly braces `}` to next line.

```
<option value="0" @if (ViewBag.country == 0) { @: selected
        }>
    NO
</option>
```

**Other options** using a `<text> element`:

```
<option value="0" @if (ViewBag.country == 0) { <text> selected</text> }>NO</option>
```

or

```
<option value="0" @{if (ViewBag.country == 0) { <text> selected</text> }}>NO</option>
```

References:

1.[Shorten-this-if-statement-in-razor-to-one-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423126/shorten-this-if-statement-in-razor-to-one-line)

2.[One-line-if-statement-with-razor-and-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341930/one-line-if-statement-with-razor-and-net)